# Bevel Tool – What exactly does LoopSlide do?

Tags: bevel

[image: Bevel Panel]

Just for curiosity.
I don't find enough information about this, even in documentation.
I don't see any difference when I use it.

Answer (score 10):

It controls whether to keep intersecting edges perpendicular to the bevel direction.

Loopslide On: gives smoother topology and better results for tight geometry
Loopslide Off: keeps perpendicular edges and even bevel width

[image]

When *Clamp Overlap* isn't enough, *Loopslide* On can keep the topology in check:

[image]

Comment: Apart that he asked for the _Bevel Tool_ instead of the _Bevel Modifier_, I would suspect it doesn't matter for the function. Only that I was wondering myself what this is for... because I can't see a difference either, at least not with the usual bevels I have to create. The functionality you explain in the answer is the _Clamp Overlap_ option...

Comment: Oh, I see... didn't look carefully enough on that screenshot... okay it gives smoother bevel results. But it doesn't keep faces from overlapping.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comments :). With *Clamp* off, *LoopSlide* still helps to keep the topology better, and overlapping faces low. We're talking corner cases - very tight geometry. I'll rephrase the wording so it's not confusing :).

Comment: I was talking about corners with tight geometry as well... with _Clamp_ off, as soon as it starts to overlap, it overlaps, no matter if _Loop Slide_ is enabled or not. In tight corners I cannot see any advantage and especially no avoiding of face overlap whatsoever: [loop_slide.gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZpK7XcUgUjw-sMAvkrMv12TuJdWi4ENb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hey, feel free to post your own answer, it's quite possible I missed something :). We're all here to learn, right? :)

Comment: Actually I had no idea what this option does until I saw your answer, so I wanted to learn from you :) Since this "moving perpendicular" is the only thing I see, there's nothing (new or additional) for me to answer here. And although you edited it out of your answer you persisted to say it helps to keep overlapping faces low. And I just can't observe this anywhere, if you could give an example for that I'd be glad to learn more...

Comment: Hey, I added a gif :)

Comment: I really want to know if there is a way of not overlapping faces without clamping... some kind of merging or anything but keep beveling further. What I don't like about clamping is, the bevel stops as soon as overlapping begins. Which means I have to disable it, overlap faces and "repair" it manually. I just hoped you knew something I didn't that would help me.

Answer (score 2):

I am the bevel tool and modifier author. Loop slide does the same in both. It only has an effect if there are unbeveled edges between two beveled edges at a vertex, and furthermore, at least one of those unbeveled edges is in a different plane than the one containing the two beveled edges.

In a circumstance like that, there is a choice where the meeting point of the offset edges from the beveled edges go. (1) it can go at the place that best makes the bevel width match the amount specification; (2) it can go on a non-beveled edge between the two.  The second may be preferred if you don't want the silhouette of the object to drastically change. That second method is what is turned on with "Loop slide".

Comment: It's so cool to get feedback from someone who actually worked on the tools we all use :). Thanks.